# our website is showing some code instead of loading

Tags: wordpress

our website url is www.technolabssoftware.com

while visiting it is showing this code:

//define('WP_CACHE', true); //Added by WP-Cache Manager define( 'WPCACHEHOME', '/home2/technoq8/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/' ); //Added by WP-Cache Manager define('W3TC_EDGE_MODE', true); // Added by W3 Total Cache /** * The base configurations of the WordPress. * * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix, * Secret Keys, WordPress Language, and ABSPATH. You can find more information * by visiting {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing * wp-config.php} Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host. * * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values. * * @package WordPress */ // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** // /** The name of the database for WordPress */ define('DB_NAME', 'technoq8_wor4'); /** MySQL database username */ define('DB_USER', 'technoq8_wor4'); /** MySQL database password */ define('DB_PASSWORD', 'technoq8_wor4'); /** MySQL hostname */ define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); /** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */ define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'); /** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */ define('DB_COLLATE', ''); /** without conflicting script of various versions. */ define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false ); /**#@+ * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts. * * Change these to different unique phrases! * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service} * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again. * * @since 2.6.0 */ define('AUTH_KEY', '|8Q?VrNPGI{%;GnIiwhtM#`#Odq%qnz+C||2m=$;$*)O&$OTbR oK6+)aY'); define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY', 'ylz<<-#cn!-:j:4c;yQ-G-8n$Gjo$6;|&~J-rxV^y~j#+;hb|h]<,73ir-ZCFE2<'); define('LOGGED_IN_KEY', 'ofEZJhikC6RiC6q2qH]-~-ZCGv_xiA5&UwhPz90ZofGt+Iej.Ep8.0vL.>+H|9qi'); define('NONCE_KEY', 'HK1LY3F_|K=C+Y/:y^$]S2|WOW|uc41l0o[H$u3iEZ}DfRfX&CA/pTdr[+pX/| c'); define('AUTH_SALT', '29[$7]XC++pGNXQ%%qVKd#KRy.jjNgZ &-+Wd7W^/#fvk7*58HhJgW%`jw*p1pQ0'); define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'SPr|cJe3F6>Vw#e+arV]JPqGET;nK%2][lr[q&x^awKv8uJ8t! ,?SV^SqW>G-@q'); define('LOGGED_IN_SALT', '=*L/Li3/<=i jLSQ9onji[IN|+rE`Nq@W-ho@36~bfDFq>$|*d,O6eoDLx

Comment: php is not running/ someone removed php tags from the file

Answer (score 0):

This is really bad! It shows your server login credetials so anyone could easily hack you.

The text shown is the content of you wp-config.php file in the root directory. As a first step, delete wp-config.php and change your database user and password.

**Edit**: Your website seems to be back up now. I strongly suggest that you change all configuration details of your wp-config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Your config is being spit out because you do not have the opening 
`<?php` tag